# Apache Camel support for parquet in HDFS or Azure Blob FileSystem (Gen2)

Tags: apache-camel, parquet, apache-arrow

I have a half-dozen data movement and conversion tasks coming up.  I'm not a Java guy, but Apache Camel looks like a supported OSS option that can handle all my scenarios except one:

I need to move data from Kafka and custom local files to parquet for archival in data lake.  It don't see Camel parquet support (nor any other data lake or big data formats).  I might be missing the "Lego pieces" needed to write parquet.

Comment: I could write to an intermediate format, like CSV or JSON, then call Python (pandas) to convert to parquet or Arrow.  But given the huge numbers of formats supported by Camel, and that it is another Apache project (can be written by Apache Arrow libraries) I'm surprised by the lack of first-class support.

Comment: These are large daily datasets that are similar to time series data, planning to use brotli compression in parquet.

Comment: Sometimes the enterprise software world and the data science world just haven't met yet :).  Are these datasets in some kind of existing format today?  Or is it a custom format?  If you wanted to avoid breaking out to python then https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr is a good choice for a Java parquet serializer.  Of course, at that point it's only a short hop to writing a custom data format and submitting it ;)  Related: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-13573